# How does a Lagrangian with delta potential transform to a Hamiltonian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, dirac-delta-distributions, branes

Suppose the Lagrangian was given as:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underbrace{\left(\dot{A(}z)^2-A(z)^2\right)+\left(\dot{Q(}z)^2\delta(z)-Q(z)^2\delta(z)\right)+2\dot{Q(}z)\cdot A(z) \delta(z)}_{= \mathcal{L}} \,\,\,dz\tag{1}$$

where Q is localized at $0$. The above are basically two harmonic oscillators that are coupled to each other in the last term. Now, if I wanted to Legendre-transform this in order to get the Hamiltonian, I wouldn't know what to do with the Dirac-delta function.

The conjugate momentum for A(z) is fairly straight forward:

$$P_A = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{A\,}(z)} = \dot{A\,}(z)\tag{2}$$

but how should I deal with the other conjugate momentum $P_Q$? Would it be

$$P_Q = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{Q\,}(z)} = \dot{Q\,}(z)\delta(z)+A(z)\delta(z)\tag{3}$$

or

$$P_Q = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\dot{Q\,}(z)\delta(z))} = \dot{Q\,}(z)+A(z).\tag{4}$$

I run into problems using the former, but the latter does not seem correct.

Comment: 3 is basically correct, and you are running into trouble because for z=0 PQ(z) is zero, and the velocity cannot be expressed in terms of the momenta. This is called a first class constraint. You have to check if the constraint is compatible with thr hamiltonian

Answer (score 1):

1. *Lagrangian formulation.* The trick is to appreciate that OP's Lagrangian 
   $$ L ~=~ \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dz ( \dot{A}(z)^2 -A(z)^2) 
   ~+~ \frac{1}{2}( \dot{Q}(0)^2 -Q(0)^2)~+~ \dot{Q}(0) A(0) \tag{A}$$
   is a combination of a bulk theory in the $A$-sector and a boundary theory in the $Q$-sector (say, living on a brane located at $z=0$).
2. [*Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). The bulk EL eq. is 
   $$ \ddot{A}(z)+A(z)~\approx~+\delta(z)\dot{Q}(0), \tag{B}$$ 
   while the boundary EL eq. is 
   $$ \ddot{Q}(0)+Q(0)~\approx~-\dot{A}(0). \tag{C}$$
   If we assume that the bulk field $A(z)$ is continuous without $\delta(z)$-contributions, then eq. (B) implies that $\dot{Q}(0)\approx 0$. Eq. (C) then implies that $\ddot{A}(0)\approx 0$. Eq. (B) then implies that $A(0)\approx 0$. Eq. (C) then implies that $Q(0)\approx 0$. In conclusion: The two harmonic oscillators $A$ and $Q$ decouple, and the amplitudes vanish at $z=0$.
3. *Momenta.* The bulk momentum is
   $$ P_A(z)~=~\frac{\delta L}{\delta \dot{A}(z)}~=~\dot{A}(z), \tag{D}$$
   while the boundary momentum is
   $$ P_Q(0)~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{Q}(0)}~=~ \dot{Q}(0)+A(0).\tag{E} $$
4. *Hamiltonian formulation.* The Hamiltonian gains a bulk and a boundary part 
   $$\begin{align} H ~&=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dz ~ P_{A}(z)\dot{A}(z)~+~P_Q(0)\dot{Q}(0)~-~L\cr~&=~\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dz ( P_{A}(z)^2 +A(z)^2) 
   ~+~ \frac{1}{2}( (P_Q(0)-A(0))^2 +Q(0)^2). \end{align}\tag{F}$$

Comment: The problem that I am working on explicitly asks to diagonalize the above Hamiltonian. The idea is to expand the $(P_Q(0)-A(0))^2$ term and get two harm. oscill. and one coupling term:  $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dz \left[P_{A}(z)^2 +A(z)^2+A(z)^2\delta(z)\right] 
~+~ \frac{1}{2}( P_Q(0)^2 +Q(0)^2) ~+~ P_Q(0)\cdot A(0)$$ I know how to diagonalize the two h.o. and the coupling term. The problem, though, is  $A(z)^2+A(z)^2\delta(z)$. I would like to somehow add them up and redefine A(z). Could I do this by defining A(z) with something that cancels the delta-function from the beginning?